# How to return colored text from a function?

Tags: python, colors, jupyter-notebook, return-type

I want to have my function return statement output be in color (apart from black). But I can't find anywhere how to do so. Tried to add `'\033[92m'` in front of the string but it only works if I `print` the string. Not working as part of my `return` statement.

```
def function():
   string = '\033[92m colored word'
   print(string)
   return string
```

`print(string)` in my function displays the color that I want (**green**) in my python notebook when I run the function. But the `retur`n statement only shows **black** color string.

[image]

Comment: Strings don't have color. They are just symbols. Whatever you use to *display* a string may have color, but there is no universal standard for this.

Comment: `return {string}` returns a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) containing one element, the value the `string` variable has in the function — in other words `{'bla bla \033[92m colored word \033[0m bla bla'}`.

Comment: What will be the solution to this problem if I want the string in the return statement in the color as print(string)? @martineau

Comment: Just return the string with the embedded color in it. If that does not work, then there is something else going on — such as a conflict with ipython's Notebook.

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong at print().

```
def function():
   string = f'bla bla \033[92m colored word \033[0m bla bla'
   print(string)
   return string
print(function())
```

If your do this:

```
def function():
   string = f'bla bla \033[92m colored word \033[0m bla bla'
   print(string)
   return string
function()
```

Your can see: 'bla bla \x1b[92m colored word \x1b[0m bla bla'